# Twilio Error - 11200 HTTPS Retrieval / Python Flask Application

Tags: python, flask, heroku, https, twilio

I am receiving a 11200 HTTPS retrieval error from the code below. Can someone please explain me how I can resolve this? (I am hosting this application on a local server and using the ngrok https 5000 URL for the twilio API)

```
from flask import Flask, Response, request
from twilio import twiml
import os
from twilio.http.http_client import TwilioHttpClient
import requests
from twilio.rest import Client


app = Flask(__name__)
port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))


account_sid = "xxx"
auth_token = "xxx"

# proxy_client = TwilioHttpClient(proxy={'http': os.environ['http_proxy'], 'https': os.environ['https_proxy']})
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)


@app.route("/")
def check_app():
    # returns a simple string stating the app is working
    return Response("It works!"), 200


@app.route("/twilio", methods=["POST"])
def inbound_sms():
    response = twiml.Response()
    # we get the SMS message from the request. we could also get the 
    # "To" and the "From" phone number as well
    inbound_message = request.form.get("Body")

    print(inbound_message)
    # we can now use the incoming message text in our Python application
    if inbound_message == "Hello":
        response.message("Hello back to you!")
    else:
        response.message("Hi! Not quite sure what you meant, but okay.")
    # we return back the mimetype because Twilio needs an XML response
    return Response(str(response), mimetype="application/xml"), 200


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up your Flask response and Twilio response, your code is actually raising an `AttributeError` with the Twilio Python Helper Library version 6.45.1 under Python 3.6.9 because Twilio doesn't have a `twiml.Response` attribute.

Change your code to the following, please note the usage of `MessagingResponse`:

```
@app.route("/twilio", methods=["POST"])
def inbound_sms():
    response = MessagingResponse()
    inbound_message = request.form.get("Body")
    if inbound_message == "Hello":
        response.message("Hello back to you!")
    else:
        response.message("Hi! Not quite sure what you meant, but okay.")
    return Response(str(response), mimetype="application/xml"), 200
```

Don't forget to add `from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse` to your imports. See also the [example in the Twilio documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-python).

I've only tested it locally but then your `/twilio` endpoint returns correct TwiML when hitting it with [HTTPie](https://httpie.io/):

```
$ http --form POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/twilio Body=Hello
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Length: 96
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 26 Feb 2021 12:15:30 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/1.0.1 Python/3.6.9

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Message>Hello back to you!</Message></Response>
```